# SharePoint Designer Workflow Unable to Send Email

Tags: email, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I have created a sharepoint 2013 workflow in sharepoint designer. when the workflow runs it gets suspended after some time, throwing the error below:
without sending the email. Please any help would be appreciated. I have also attached a picture to show what happens:

[image]

RequestorId: 494afcef-ef83-bf40-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 400 {"error":{"code":"-2130242040, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient."}}} {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"X-SP-SERVERSTATE":["ReadOnly=0"],"DATASERVICEVERSION":["3.0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["101"],"SPRequestGuid":["494afcef-ef83-bf40-9ddb-f17a22730f4e"],"request-id":["494afcef-ef83-bf40-9ddb-f17a22730f4e"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["16.0.0.4327"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Wed, 14 Sep 2016 16:15:20 GMT"],"Server":["Microsoft-IIS/8.5"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

Comment: As per exception details *The e-mail message cannot be sent. Make sure the e-mail has a valid recipient.* - is your **to** field being set properly?

Comment: Thanks, the email is actually correct in the format firstname.lastname@domain.com

Answer (score 2):

The issue is SP2013 WFs will NOT send to external email addresses.  You must create a SP2010, yes, a SP2010 (ten for emphasis) WF to send an email to an external domain address.

Comment: Hi Rugby, I have a simpler question, but my workflow is for calendar, Please see and advice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073154/sharepoint-designer-create-workflow-to-schedule-emails-on-specific-dates-from

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who is still looking for an answer to this. You need to add the e-mail you want to forward the emails to to the Members/Owners lists.

See this SharePoint Designer 2013 Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Also, the SharePoint 2013 Workflow does not support to send emails to the Distribution group/list. Read [this](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/13867905-sharepoint-2013-workflow-email-to-distribution-lis) article.